# What is the best way to remove a lot of dead cat grass leaves?

Tags: leaves, pruning, grass

I have multiple groups of cat grass for decoration. They're about 6 months old and some of the leaves died, making it less appealing. Since there are a lot of them, what would be the best way to get rid of them quickly? I don't want to cut them one by one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean what is usually meant by "cat grass" (grass intended for indoor cats to nibble on:) Start new "cat grass" (typically oats) - pull up the old, dying stuff, put the new stuff in its place (compost the old.)

It is a grain with a "less than 1 year" lifecycle. Trying to keep it alive for a long time, it will inevitably look bad.

Comment: Grass in the pic looks like some kind of clump grass rather than oats. Or is it set in little separate pots? If the later, Primož will get longer, pretty life out of them by using deeper pots. https://www.google.com/search?q=clump+grass&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, Ecnerwal, Bamboo there are two different species known as "cat grass". One is oats which is an annual grain crop. The other is a perennial grass Dactylitis Glomerata (commonly called Cocksfoot in the UK) which is what the OP's picture looks like. In that case, you can cut it down just like the grass on your lawn without any problems. One basic feature of grasses is that they grow from the bottom of the leaf, not from the top like many other plant species, so being cut down (or eaten) doesn't check the growing process.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, unless you want to risk cutting the whole lot down to an inch or less and hoping they regrow, there is no way to avoid trimming out the brown leaves individually.